# save ajax response to jquery variable

Tags: jquery, ajax

Simple question,
I know that ajax is asynchronous, i have the following function that is working with alert of the response,is working BUT, my problem is that i want to some how store the result from the ajax response in a var of a modal among other text that is showing when pressing the button to show the modal.. i have tried async:false but its not working.. :( here is my function

```
     getVersion: function() {
     $.ajax({
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'GET',
      url: this.options.url.generalsUrl + '/getAppVersion',
      cache: false,
      async: false,
      success: function(response) {
      alert(response.VERSION);//ok this is for testing
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
          alert("There was an error retrieving the version of the application.");
      }
  });
```

},

but then somewhere else in the function of the modal button i want to stick it among the other text of the var content here is the other function not showning all cause i dont want to be lazy..

```
    var imgAbout = $('#topright-menu ul.menu-divmenu > li > a > img[src$="about.png"]');
    imgAbout.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var modal = (self.modal());      
var content = $('self.getVersion()') + //this line is bad how can i show the response?
              "in the following browsers have been tested: <br>" +
              '<img src="images/ie.png" width="45" height="45"/>Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.17239<br>' +
              '<img src="images/mozilla.png" width="45" height="45"/>Mozilla Firefox 32.0<br>' + 
              '<img src="images/chrome.png" width="45" height="45"/>Google Chrome 37.0.2062.103 m<br>';

        var $div_container = $('<div></div>')
                .addClass('jtable-main-container');

        var $div_title = $('<div></div>').addClass('jtable-title')
                .appendTo($div_container);
        $('<div></div>').addClass('jtable-title-text')
                .text('Information for the application')
                .appendTo($div_title);

        var $table = $('<table></table>').appendTo($div_container);
        var $row = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo($table);
        var $cell = $('<td></td>').html(content).appendTo($row);                   
        $('#jsn-pos-left').hide();
        modal.open({
            content: $div_container                
        });

    });
```

any help guys? i believe its an easy thing,, but hard for me.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all thank you so much !!!
**Iftah
Teo
Azadrum**
for the help really appreciated!!! 
so just for future use in case someone else need it .. i changed it and i have put inside the getVersion function success  the modal function, and it worked like a charm so here is the working code..
for the button

```
      var imgAbout = $('#topright-menu ul.menu-divmenu > li > a > img[src$="about.png"]');
      imgAbout.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();            
        self.getVersion();      
  });
```

and for the getVersion function with the modal function inside

```
      getVersion: function() {      
    var self = this;      
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        url: this.options.url.generalsUrl + '/getAppVersion',
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        success: function(response) {            
            var modal = (self.modal());      
            var content = "<span class='version'>" + "The Version of the application is: " + response.VERSION + "<br>" +
            "The application has been tested with the following browsers: " + "<br>" +
            '<img src="../images/browser_icons/ie.png" width="45" height="45"/>Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.17239<br>' +
            '<img src="../images/browser_icons/mozilla.png" width="45" height="45"/>Mozilla Firefox 32.0<br>' + 
            '<img src="../images/browser_icons/chrome.png" width="45" height="45"/>Google Chrome 37.0.2062.103 m<br>';
            var $div_container = $('<div></div>')
            .addClass('jtable-main-container');                                
            var $div_title = $('<div></div>').addClass('jtable-title')
            .appendTo($div_container);
            $('<div></div>').addClass('jtable-title-text')
            .text('Πληροφορίες για την εφαρμογή')
            .appendTo($div_title);
            var $table = $('<table></table>').appendTo($div_container);
            var $row = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo($table);
            var $cell = $('<td></td>').html(content).appendTo($row);                   
            $('#jsn-pos-left').hide();
            modal.open({
                content: $div_container                
            });
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            alert("There was an error retrieving the version of the application.");
        }
    });
},
```

once again thank you all for the help..problem solved!topic closed.

Comment: Your thanks is appreciated - you are welcome! but in this website instead of saying "thanks" you can up-vote the answer (up-arrow to the left) and accept one of the answers (check mark to the left). This implies 'thanks' and also rewards the person who answered and also removes the question from the 'unanswered' list, and also, most importantly helps future readers find good answers.

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery Deferred for this.

```
 getVersion: function() {
   var d = new $.Deferred();
   $.ajax({
     dataType: 'json',
     type: 'GET',
     url: this.options.url.generalsUrl + '/getAppVersion',
     cache: false,
     async: false,
     success: function(response) {
        d.resolve(response.VERSION);
        alert(response.VERSION);//ok this is for testing
     },
     error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
         alert("There was an error retrieving the version of the application.");
     }
   });
   return d.promise();
 }. ...
```

then you can simply call var version = yourObj.getVersion();

Answer (score 0):

You have three simple choices,

1. Load the version when the page is ready - this is good if this version doesn't change. Then you can simply save it in a global variable and use it when you build the `content` html string for your modal.
2. If you want to load the version as the modal opens, then you can request the AJAX in the click event, and in the AJAX reply handler (`success` function) build the `content` html string and show the modal there.  This is good if the AJAX reply is quick enough.
3. if the AJAX reply is slow and you want to present the modal right away on click, you can put a placeholder into the content string that you can replace with DOM manipulation, eg.

   ```
   // in the click handler show the modal:
   var content =  "<span class='version'> in the following browsers have..."
   // show modal
   // then call ajax, and in success function fill the placeholder:
   $('.version').text('Version is '+ajax_result)
   ```

(you may want to put a spinning 'loading' icon as the placeholder)

Answer (score 0):

Create a placeholder for the ajax result in your dialog. And put the result of the ajax request to this placeholder when it is loaded.

....

```
 success: function(response) {
  $(".ajaxResultPlaceholder").html(response);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
      alert("There was an error retrieving the version of the application.");
  }
```

....

```
var content = '<span class="ajaxResultPlaceholder"><img src="/loader.png" /></span>' + //this line is bad how can i show the response?
              "in the following browsers have been tested: <br>" +
              '<img src="images/ie.png" width="45" height="45"/>Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.17239<br>' +
              '<img src="images/mozilla.png" width="45" height="45"/>Mozilla Firefox 32.0<br>' + 
              '<img src="images/chrome.png" width="45" height="45"/>Google Chrome 37.0.2062.103 m<br>';
```

...

```
        modal.open({
            content: $div_container                
        });

self.getVersion();
```

...